# C#: Shift left assignment operator behavior

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I'm running code that sometimes yields this:

```
UInt32 current;  
int left, right;  

...

//sometimes left == right and no shift occurs
current <<= (32 + left - right);

//this works
current <<= (32 - right);
current <<= left;
```

It appears for any value >= 32, only the value % 32 is shifted.  Is there some "optimization" occurring in the framework?

Comment: The problem is unclear.

`UInt32` has 32 value bits. If you shift it left by 32 bits, you will get all bits zero (because you've shifted all value bits "away"). If you shift by more, you will still get all bits zero, so the effect is exactly the same. What did you expect?

Comment: It's not an optimization; that's just how the operator is defined to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# 3.0 language specification, 7.8 "Shift operators":

> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> - When the type of x is int or uint, the shift count is given by the low-order five  bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x1F.
> - When the type of x is long or ulong, the shift count is given by the low-order six  bits of count. In other words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x3F.